How to align title in the stepper widget flutter
This the code I have:
class ONDCOrderStatus extends StatelessWidget {
  ONDCOrderStatus({super.key});

  final List<String> orderStatus = [
    "Accepted",
    "Ready",
    "Pick up",
    "on the way",
    "Delivered"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [

        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: List.generate(orderStatus.length, (index) =>Text(orderStatus[index]))

        ),

        IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                //Text(orderStatus[0]),
                Row(
                  // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(AppAssetUrls.ondcAccepted),
                    AnimatedDivider(color: ONDCColor.kONDCAccentColor)
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(

              children: [
              //  Text(orderStatus[1]),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(AppAssetUrls.ondcAccepted),
                    AnimatedDivider(color: ONDCColor.kONDCAccentColor)
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
               // Text(orderStatus[2]),
                Row(
                  // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(AppAssetUrls.ondcAccepted),
                    AnimatedDivider(color: ONDCColor.kONDCAccentColor)
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
               // Text(orderStatus[3]),
                Row(
                  // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(AppAssetUrls.ondcAccepted),
                    AnimatedDivider(color: ONDCColor.kONDCAccentColor,width: 0.16,)
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Image.asset(AppAssetUrls.ondcAccepted),

              ],
            ),

          ]),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedDivider extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final double width;

  const AnimatedDivider({super.key, required this.color, this.width=0.15});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      height: 2,
      width: Get.width*width,
      //   width: 40,

      // Adjust the width of the animated line as needed
      color: color,
      // Change the color of the animated line as needed
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
    );
  }
}

I am getting this widget but what I want is this alignment

I am getting this widget but what I want is this alignment

